# What is a Format of csv plugin datasource string in mapnik

Tags: mapnik, c++

I have tried that Format Is that is a correct format to pass to CSV plugin,the sample C++ code is given Below:

```
std::string csv_string("wkt,Name POLYGON((5.123456 51.6, 6.8 52.6, 7.8 51.6, 5.123456 51.6)),Roads" );

  {     parameters p;
        p["type"]="csv";
        p["inline"]=csv_string;
        layer lyr("Roads");
        lyr.set_datasource(datasource_cache::instance().create(p)); 
   }
```